# send a value from another field as a argument for ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have following code in a new.html.erb page.

```
<h3>Create Make Payment </h3>   
    <%= simple_form_for(@payment) do |f| %>   <%= f.error_notification %> <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, collection:@arr,:required=>true,:id=>"payment_email" ,:class=>"chosen-select"%>   </div>   <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id,:value=>User.find_by_email(ar).id,:id=>"user_id" %>   </div>  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :amount,:required=>true%>   </div>

    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :desc, as: :text ,:required=>true%>   </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>   </div> <% end %>
```

On chage in the payment_email select box I want a ajax request to take place. I have done the following.

1. Added `respond_to do |format| format.js` in the create action in payments controller.
2. I have written the following in a js file.

> ```
> jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
>   'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
> })
>
> jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
>   this.onChange(function() {
>     $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
>     return false;
>   })
>   return this;
> };
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $("#payment_email").submitWithAjax();
> })
> ```

1. created a file called create.js.erb and entered the following in it.

   `$("#user_id").value("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => user_id)) %>");`
2. I have created a partial _user_id.html.erb to print the value to be changed.

Now where I am stuck is that, I am not sure how to send the value of payment_email through ajax to create.js.erb where I will use it to get the required User id. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [Change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#payment_email" ).change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/controller/action",
      data: { email: $( "#payment_email" ); }
      });
  });
});
```